# Best way to go from RStudio project development to scheduled R Script

Tags: r, rstudio, scheduled-tasks, tidyverse

I am developing processes for collecting, cleaning and storing various data sets. The development is done with RStudio projects. I won't say I'm following every tidyverse/RStudio workflow recommendation but in general I'm using that framework-- relevant now is that I'm using standard subdirectories and the `here` package for referencing them.

Every project has a `MAIN.R` script that ultimately `source`s the functions from the other scripts-- one only needs to run `MAIN.R` to execute the process. I did this not only for simplicity but also because the long-term intent is to have this be a scheduled process.

For now at least my method for scheduling R Scripts is with Windows Task Scheduler. Getting an R Script scheduled and running is not a problem. The issue is the contextual assumptions of developing within a project: `source(here("CODE", "some-file.R"))` fails when I run `MAIN.R` outside of the scope of the project.

One obvious solution would be to hard-code the project location as one of the parameters. I would need to have two different `MAIN.R` files, one for development that uses the project and one that uses that parameter for scheduling. I don't hate that idea, don't love it as it someone nullifies the whole point of the project/here approach. Is there a more elegant solution that someone else has created that I couldn't find on Google, or better workaround ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the solution described here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-play-nice-with-taskscheduler-r-studio-projects-and-here/24406/2 .

I didn't have to make any changes to the `MAIN.R` script. Instead, I scheduled it directly but added the project directory to the "Starts In" argument of the Windows Task Scheduler task.